# Two table pivot to display matrix for user types and assigned roles

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:
- UserType
- UserTypeRole

UserType:

```
| UserTypeCode      | DisplayTitle        | Description         |
|-------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| AdministratorUser | Administrator User  | Administrator User  |
| GeneralUser       | General User        | General User        |
| READONLY          | RO User             | RO User             |
| TeamManager       | Team Manager        | Teamd Manager       |
```

UserTypeRole:

```
| UserTypeCode      | ApplicationRoleCode    |
|-------------------|------------------------|
| AdministratorUser | CaseDocument           |
| AdministratorUser | CaseNote               |
| AdministratorUser | CaseNoteAdd            |
| AdministratorUser | Dashboard              |
| GeneralUser       | CaseDocument           |
| GeneralUser       | CaseNote               |
| GeneralUser       | CaseNoteAdd            |
| GeneralUser       | CaseOverview           |
| GeneralUser       | CaseSearch             |
| GeneralUser       | Dashboard              |
| READONLY          | CaseDocument           |
| READONLY          | CaseNote               |
| READONLY          | CaseOverview           |
| READONLY          | CaseSearch             |
| READONLY          | Dashboard              |
| TeamManager       | CaseDocument           |
| TeamManager       | CaseDocumentEdit       |
| TeamManager       | CaseNote               |
| TeamManager       | CaseNoteAdd            |
| TeamManager       | CaseNoteDelete         |
| TeamManager       | CaseNoteEdit           |
| TeamManager       | CaseOverview           |
| TeamManager       | CaseSearch             |
| TeamManager       | CaseStateEdit          |
```

I also have a ApplicationRole table which contains a list of all of the ApplicationRoles and a description of each.

Not all users have all types, and I'm trying to produce a matrix with 'Yes' and 'No' values like this:

```
| ApplicationRoleCode | AdministratorUser | GeneralUser | READONLY | TeamManager |
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------|----------|-------------| 
| Dashboard           | Yes               | Yes         | Yes      | Yes         |
| CaseDocument        | Yes               | Yes         | Yes      | Yes         |
| CashNoteAdd         | Yes               | Yes         | No       | Yes         |
.... etc
```

I understand the basic requirement is an outer join from UserTypeRole to the UserType and the NULL values become the 'No' value, but I'm struggling to PIVOT the data:

```
SELECT ar.ApplicationRoleCode, utr.UserTypeCode, ut.DisplayTitle, ar.Description 
FROM ApplicationRole ar
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserTypeRole utr ON utr.ApplicationRoleCode = ar.ApplicationRoleCode
INNER JOIN UserType ut ON ut.UserTypeCode = utr.UserTypeCode
```

Any tips?

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Most people have problem enough with LEFT JOIN... It's easier to understand `main table left join optional data`, instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: You probably want to google "SQL Server dynamic pivot".

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've bee busily Googling all morning but the examples are all SUMs of financial data. What do I need to PIVOT on? ApplicationRoleCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #DataSource 
(
    [UserTypeCode] VARCHAR(64)
   ,[ApplicationRoleCode] VARCHAR(64)
);

INSERT INTO #DataSource ([UserTypeCode], [ApplicationRoleCode])
VALUES   ('AdministratorUser', 'CaseDocument')
        ,('AdministratorUser', 'CaseNote')
        ,('AdministratorUser', 'CaseNoteAdd ')
        ,('AdministratorUser', 'Dashboard')
        ,('GeneralUser', 'CaseDocument')
        ,('GeneralUser', 'CaseNote')
        ,('GeneralUser', 'CaseNoteAdd')
        ,('GeneralUser', 'CaseOverview')
        ,('GeneralUser', 'CaseSearch')
        ,('GeneralUser', 'Dashboard')
        ,('READONLY', 'CaseDocument')
        ,('READONLY', 'CaseNote')
        ,('READONLY', 'CaseOverview')
        ,('READONLY', 'CaseSearch')
        ,('READONLY', 'Dashboard')
        ,('TeamManager', 'CaseDocument')
        ,('TeamManager', 'CaseDocumentEdit')
        ,('TeamManager', 'CaseNote')
        ,('TeamManager', 'CaseNoteAdd')
        ,('TeamManager', 'CaseNoteDelete')
        ,('TeamManager', 'CaseNoteEdit')
        ,('TeamManager', 'CaseOverview')
        ,('TeamManager', 'CaseSearch')
        ,('TeamManager', 'CaseStateEdit');

DECLARE @DynammicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@DynamicPIVOTColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@DynamicColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @DynamicPIVOTColumns = STUFF
                          (
                                (
                                SELECT ',[' + CAST([UserTypeCode] AS VARCHAR(12)) + ']'
                                FROM #DataSource
                                GROUP BY [UserTypeCode]
                                ORDER BY [UserTypeCode]
                                FOR XML PATH('') ,TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                                ,1
                                ,1
                                ,''
                          );

SET @DynamicColumns = STUFF
                          (
                                (
                                SELECT ',ISNULL([' + CAST([UserTypeCode] AS VARCHAR(12)) + '], ''No'') AS [' +CAST([UserTypeCode] AS VARCHAR(12)) +']'
                                FROM #DataSource
                                GROUP BY [UserTypeCode]
                                ORDER BY [UserTypeCode]
                                FOR XML PATH('') ,TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                                ,1
                                ,1
                                ,''
                          );



SET @DynammicTSQLStatement = N'
SELECT [ApplicationRoleCode]
      ,' + @DynamicColumns + '
FROM
(
    SELECT ''Yes'' AS [ID]
          ,[UserTypeCode]
          ,[ApplicationRoleCode]
    FROM #DataSource
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([ID]) FOR [UserTypeCode] IN (' + @DynamicPIVOTColumns + ')
) PVT';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynammicTSQLStatement;

DROP TABLE #DataSource;
```

[image]